# How can I join a variable number (via function input) of zeroes to a string of an integer?

Tags: string, python-3.x, string-length, digit

I am trying to create a function that will convert input datetime parameters for a specified date into a single datetime string - without using the datetime module.

I know that I can format the length of a string like so:

```
minute = 7
print('%.2f' %minute)
# 7.00
```

Why then does the code below not work as I intend?

```
print('%2.f' %minute)
# 7 but I want 07
print('%2.2f' %minute)
# 7.00 but I want 07.00
```

My goal is to write a function that will take variable number of digits (example: 2 digits for minutes as above, but 4 digits for years). This way, I can add all the stringified datetime parameters into a single string using the process below. (I plan to get it to work for lists or arrays of each given datetime parameter).

```
def prefixify(integer, num_digits):
    res = str(integer)
    if len(res) == num_digits:
        pass
    else:
        num_zeroes = num_digits - len(res)
        # do stuff to res
    return res

year = 1999
month = 10
day = 27
hour = 11
minute = 17
second = 23

def stringify_datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second):
    return str(year) + '/' + str(month) + '/' + str(day) + '    ' + str(hour) + ':' + str(minute) + ':' + str(second)

print(stringify_datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))
#1999/10/27    11:17:23
```

Comment: To get float padding `'{:0>5.2f}'.format(7)`

Comment: That works, thanks. Is there a way to set a variable in place of the 5?